# Activation energy as a function of defects

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, semiconductor-physics, thermal-conductivity, nanoscience

Electrical conductivity has a form of Arrhenius equation. It is assumed that activation energy decreases with defect density in the insulating state and becomes zero in the conducting state. Can one explain this assumption?

Comment: It would be nice if more than the tag would tell a reader that you seem to be talking about a semiconductor.

Comment: The number of acceptors/donors that are ionized (have given up a hole or electron) is an Arrhenius function of temperature, that is true.  I'm not sure that I would structure the overall conductivity of a semiconductor as a function of a varying activation energy.  Perhaps you could clarify where (what book) you have seen this assumption?

Comment: This was an assumption in an article. Where conductivity are considered to be function of defects.